# SQL, query fk1 in relation table that with fk2 condition

Tags: sql, select, relation

The caption cannot explain my question well, please read:

I have a relation table connect `Product` and `Product_Type`, now I want to select the product that its type_id belongs to 7 and 23. Which means the product belongs to type 7 and type 23. But I cannot find a simple sql to select the product_id.

```
SELECT * FROM pdt_type_rel
where pdt_type_id=7 or pdt_type_id=23
```

[image]

As the query result shows, only product (id=5) is what I want. But how can I simply select only product (id=5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the product and then choose only groups that have both types

```
select pdt_id
from pdt_type_rel
where pdt_type_id in (7,23)
group by pdt_id
having count(distinct pdt_type_id) = 2
```

Since a single record can't have both values you need to look at the whole group of all `pdt_id`

Comment: Select only the product types that you want to look for. Group by the product id and then select only those with the having clause that have both product types. You can do this by counting unique product types. It must be 2 -> 7 and 23.

Answer (score 0):

you mean, you want to select records with pdt_type_id 7 or 23 and with pdt_id of 5? If I am right, try this.

`SELECT * FROM pdt_type_rel
where pdt_type_id IN (7,23) AND pdt_id =5`

Comment: Please see juergen's answer